# How to programmatically access JavaScript variables in a website via Python

Tags: javascript, python

I don't even know if this is possible, but I'm hoping there's a way to automate gathering data that are held in a JavaScript object via Python. As an example, I'm trying to access the chart data from http://cryptocurrencychart.com/top/10.

I thought the easiest way to do this would be via the `requests` module, and just look for the SVG elements that hold the data, such as `dom.select('.c3-chart-lines .c3-chart-line .c3-shapes-Bitcoin circle')`, where `dom` is the resulting object from a call to `BeautifulSoup`, and then use `.get('cy')` to get the values. However, if you compare the values of the `cy` attributes to the actual values on the chart, they don't line up.

I realized, however, that I could just open the developer console and access the data via `console.log(CryptoCurrencyChart.chart.data());`. In order to save these data to a text file, I had to create a link on the webpage, with the base-64 encoded data as the href, and then manually click the link.

My question is whether or not this can be done programmatically via something like Python so that I can automate it for future grabs of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Selenium to get the `CryptoCurrencyChart.chart.data()` object

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver

link = 'http://cryptocurrencychart.com/top/10'

class Scraper(object):
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('headless')
        options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome-unstable'
        options.add_argument('window-size=1200x600')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

    def scrape(self):
        self.driver.get(link)
        result = self.driver.execute_script('return CryptoCurrencyChart.chart.data()')
        self.driver.quit()
        return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scraper = Scraper()
    scraper.scrape()
```

Running `self.driver.execute_script('return CryptoCurrencyChart.chart.data()')` will give you 3 arrays with 360 elements each.